# How split over a string with a first and last index using java?

Tags: java, split

I want to split over a string (exemple : **ABC-{9090}**) with a first and last index using java

I want to get just the value between {} --> output : 9090

Comment: that is not "splitting", it's clever use of substring.

Comment: @Stultuske Or, better yet, use a regex matcher.  But, no effort shown, no answer given.

Comment: The regex post above would be good enough to create the regex, how to use a regex in java is asked enough here to be find easily.

Comment: you can use replaceAll like so `"ABC-{9090}".replaceAll("[^\\{]+\\{(.*?)\\}.*", "$1");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below replaceAll for this purpose:

```
public class StringParsing {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "ABC-{9090}";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^\\{]+\\{(.*?)\\}.*", "$1"));

    }
}
```